# Can I say "I will work for this company for some time"?

Tags: phrases

I mean I will continue to work for this company for maybe some months or some years, so can I use "for some time" as I mentioned in the title. What would a native speaker say?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common term for this would be "for the foreseeable future".

> I will work for this company for the foreseeable future.

[Definition](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/for-the-foreseeable-future):

> If you say that something will happen for the foreseeable future, you think that it will continue to happen for a long time.  e.g. *Profit and dividend growth looks like being above average for the foreseeable future.*

---

If, on the other hand, you plan to continue working for your company before moving to his company. You should use the term "until".

> I will work for this company until I join your company.

[Until definition](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/until):

> conjunction
>
> up to the time that or when; till: He read until his guests arrived.

Comment: Thank you, Ronan, I was replying a mail to a manager from another company who invite me to join his company. I want to imply that I want to join him, maybe several months later, and I want to make the mail sound a bit more hopeful. For this scenario, is "for the foreseeable future" the best choice?

Comment: Yes, this would make it seem like you want to work for him as long as possible.

Comment: You may want to say "I plan to work" or "I intend to work" rather than "I will work". To me, it sounds a bit awkward to predict the future rather than stating a present intention or expectation.

Comment: @Ronan, I thinks there's some misunderstandings, what I'm trying to say is "I'll continue to work for *current* company for some time", then I'll leave current company and join his. I don't want him to think that it would take a long time for me to leave my current company, that sounds hopeless to him.

Comment: Okay, that is a slightly different question. I will edit my answer to show that variation.

Comment: "I will **continue working** for this company for some time."

Answer (score 0):

> "I'll work for this company for *as long as* it takes, then I'll join yours."

[**as long as**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/as+long+as): for or during just the lenght of time that.

Answer (score 0):

> I mean I will continue to work for this company for maybe some months or some years, so can I use "for some time" as I mentioned in the title. What would a native speaker say? Thanks in advance.>

You could write something like this to sound interested and hopeful:

*Thank you, ...[so and so], for your confidence in my abilities as ...[such and such position]. I am confident I will be an asset to your company. However, I can not accept your offer at the present time. And I will be more than happy to revisit this question in the near future.*

Answer (score -1):

It would be a good sentence if it were "I will work for a few months/days/years in this company".